# hyphen in key for json using Jbuilder instead of underscore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, jbuilder

I'm trying to make this json by jbuilder

```
{
  "query": { 
    "bool": { 
      "must": [
        { "match": { "source-id":2}}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

and here is my code

```
query = Jbuilder.encode do |json|
                  json.query do
                    json.bool do
                      json.must do
                        json.match do
                          json.source-id source.id
                        end
                      end
                    end
                  end
                end
```

I got this error message

> syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_do or '{' or
>   '('
>                             json.source-id source.id
>                                                  ^  from /Users/amir/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:65:in
>   `start'   from
>   /Users/amir/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/console_helper.rb:9:in`
>   start'   from
>   /Users/amir/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in
>   `console'     from
>   /Users/amir/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in`
>   run_command!'    from
>   /Users/amir/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in
>   `<top (required)>'    from
>   /Users/amir/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in`require'     from
>   /Users/amir/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'    from
>   /Users/amir/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in`load_dependency'     from
>   /Users/amir/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'     from
>   /Users/amir/source/innovate/self_driving_ideas/bin/rails:9:in`'  from
>   /Users/amir/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'    from
>   /Users/amir/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in`block in load'   from
>   /Users/amir/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'     from
>   /Users/amir/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in`load'    from
>   /Users/amir/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/commands/rails.rb:6:in
>   `call'    from
>   /Users/amir/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/command_wrapper.rb:38:in`
>   call'    from
>   /Users/amir/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:191:in
>   `block in serve'  from
>   /Users/amir/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:161:in`
>   fork'    from
>   /Users/amir/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:161:in
>   `serve'   from
>   /Users/amir/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in`
>   block in run'    from
>   /Users/amir/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in
>   `loop'    from
>   /Users/amir/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in`
>   run'     from
>   /Users/amir/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in
>   `<top (required)>'    from
>   /Users/amir/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'   from
>   /Users/amir/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is with having hyphen in `source-id` key name. Try doing this if `source_id` works as key.

```
query = Jbuilder.encode do |json|
              json.query do
                json.bool do
                  json.must do
                    json.match do
                      json.source_id source.id
                    end
                  end
                end
              end
            end
```

UPDATE::

Otherwise you can do this to get the key formatted:

```
Jbuilder.encode do |json|
  json.key_format!  ->(key) { (key=="source_id") ? "source-id" : key}
  json.query do
    json.bool do
      json.must do
        json.match do
          json.source_id source.id
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

To transform all strings:

```
Jbuilder.encode do |json|
  json.key_format!  :dasherize
  json.query do
    json.bool do
      json.must do
        json.match do
          json.source_id source.id
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Or Use `set!` syntax like `json.set! "source-id", source.id`

Comment: no i don't want it to be underscore , it should be hyphen

Comment: you would have to use another method to format keys, if it's just source_id which you want with hypen then hardcode it, the way i have shown. Otherwise use `gsub("_", "-")` as formatter

Comment: the second one has error ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)

Comment: I am using stringifying to test the second one like below and seems to be working fine

Comment: Jbuilder.encode do |json|
  json.key_format!  ->(key) { (key=="source_id") ? "source-id" : key}
  json.query do
    json.bool do
      json.must do
        json.match do
          json.source_id "source.id"
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

Comment: post the stack trace, may be i can help

Comment: ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)
 from /Users/amir/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/extend-command.rb:150:in `irb_source'
 from /Users/amir/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/extend-command.rb:154:in `irb_source'
 from (irb):139:in `block (5 levels) in irb_binding'
 from /Users/amir/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/jbuilder-2.6.0/lib/jbuilder.rb:38:in `block in set!'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150870/discussion-between-vijay-agrawal-and-amir).